# How do I solve this - npm ERR! code ENOENT

Tags: npm, npm-install, enoent

I am trying to install the dependencies from a project I cloned from GitHub to my local machine. I have been getting this error for weeks now. Any help will be appreciated.

Note: I have cloned this repo many times without this error and all of a sudden this started happening

[image]

Things I have tried:

- Deleted node modules
- deleted package-lock
- reinstalled node and npm
- uninstalled node and used NVM to install LTS
- Cleaned npm cache using force
- Deactivated my antivirus
- Stopped and instance of VS code on task manager
- Used command prompt as Admin